# Access the submitted object from within a ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, threadpool

`public void execute(Runnable command)`

This command object contains the submitted object, but it seems to have been wrapped.

How can I access the submitted object from within a custom thread pool executor? Or is it not such a good idea to try and access the submitted object from inside a ThreadPoolExecutor's before/after/execute methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `execute`, use `submit`, which returns a `Future`, which is a handle to the task. Here's some example code:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

Callable<String> task = new Callable<String>() {
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "hello world";
    }
};

Future<String> future = service.submit(task);
```

Although you can't access the task directly, you can still interact with it:

```
future.cancel(); // Won't start task if not already started
String result = future.get(); // blocks until thread has finished calling task.call() and returns result
future.isDone(); // true if complete
```

You can also interact with the service:

```
service.shutdown(); //etc
```

**EDITED TO INCORPORATE COMMENTS:**

If you want to do some logging, use an [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) to override the `afterExecute()` method, like this:

```
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1)) {
        @Override
        protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)
        {
            // Do some logging here
            super.afterExecute(r, t);
        }
    };
```

Override other methods as required.

Quick plug: IMHO, the bible for this subject is [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) - I recommend you buy it and read it.

Comment: Thanks, I am already using the submit(Runnable task, V result) call, which returns a future. I am trying to do some logging within the threadpoolexecutor, specifically which task was just completed, just to help with debugging. The other option is to do a blocking get() over the future object, but that seems like polling to me for such a simple task, specially when I can see the method afterExecute(), which tells me that some task was just completed.